# transaction status aborted gtigger clr

Tags: sql, triggers, transactions, clr, msdtc

I have clr trigger deployed on two different machines with sql 2012 express, and the behawior is deeferent. One (win 8 pro) has active current transaction status and the other (win 7 pro) has aborted. Msdtc is started on each computer.
Here's my code sample

```
public partial class Triggers
{
  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlTrigger(Name = "WTrigger", Target = "Wyp", Event = "FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE")]
  public static void WTrigger ()
  {
      Transaction trans = Transaction.Current; // trans has status aborted
      SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Update happen in test table");
  }
}
```

Can somone explain my why the transaction is aborted, with out any action in trigger?